# Prove the dimension of span of vectors $v_1,\dots, v_m$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is at most m

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove dim(span($v_1,\dots, v_m)) \leq m$ for $v_1,\dots, v_m  \in \mathbb{R}^n$. I think one can prove it neatly as follows, but I am not sure if it is correct or rigorous. Let V = span(v1,...,vm), so the vectors v1,...,vm span V. By Steinitz exchange lemma, we can have at most $m$ linearly independent vectors $v_1, . . . , v_m$ in V , that is at most $m$ basis vectors. By the definition of dimension this
means that the dimension of V is at most $m$ so dim(span($v_1,\dots, v_m)) \leq m$.

Comment: It's correct !!

Comment: From any spanning set you can extract a basis.

Comment: We $n \leq m$ l.i vectors in $V$, any another vector is a linear combination of this ones. So, $\dim V = n$

Comment: Nice using Steinitz but non-necssary. You can also used an easy proof by contradiction. Try it as exercise, it is very easy.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Steinitz, but using it is fine.

If one of the vectors in $\{v_1,\dots,v_m\}$ is a linear combination of the others (that is, the set is linearly dependent), removing it from the set doesn't change the span (prove it).

Continue until you have to stop because the set is linearly independent. Then you have a basis, which obviously has at most $m$ elements.